# Text cannot be used as a jsx component it instance type 'Text' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: typescript, react-native, jsx, tsx

Receiving following error:

Text cannot be used as a jsx component it instance type 'Text' is not a valid JSX element
My file is .tsx as I in a minute need it to be typescript as I will be needing RootState.

I have tried the following so far:

- Ensured that TS is intalled globally
- added ' "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true ' tsconfig.json
- devDependencies for typescript is there.
- dependencies: "react": "17.0.2", "react-dom": "17.0.2",

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function ChatScreen({navigation}){
    return(

    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat')}
            style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Chat Screen</Text>
    </View>
    
    );
}
```

Can't seem to understand why I'm not allowed to use JSX components inside my TSX file. Hope one can help understand.

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Hello @SeanMC it appears that this is a long lasting issue which haven't been resolved. I ended up re-installing node modules and changing dependencies multiple times before it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your package.json

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.38"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatly that did not do the trick either... 

are there anything else than npm install -g typescript

I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can add <React.Fragment> :

```
return(
   <React.Fragment>
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat')}
            style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Chat Screen</Text>
    </View>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
```

here for [more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Comment: Unfortunatly that didn't do the trick. 

I receive the same error.

Comment: sorry about that, how about Wrapping the whole component like <> </>?

Comment: Thanks! It however ended up being a long standing issue.